# Ruby on Rails 5 bower:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

Soy súper nuevo en Rails y estoy tratando de aprender lo más que puedo.

Al tratar de hacer **bower:install** tengo el siguiente error.

> NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #

Estoy tratando de seguir el siguiente curso y en la instalación tengo ese error que no puedo solucionar.

http://blog.gmartinez.net/sistema-de-gestion-de-negocios-con-ruby-on-rails-5-parte-ii/

Les agradezco desde ya si me pueden dar una mano 
Saludos desde Uruguay

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tenía era: en lugar de `assets ‘bootstrap-sass-official’` debería haber escrito **asset** ‘bootstrap-sass-official’

mil gracias a todos